# There's possible to pass PHP Post using Jquery to a Constructor Class In a Simple MVC Structure?

Tags: php, jquery, directory-structure

Here is my JS code I'm trying to pass the data like a post to the class, I want to keep the integrity of the class. I want to get the form data, and via Jquery Ajax pass it as a post, and by different action it receives data values to be passed to the model and rendered by the view.

//Pass a POST to the PHP controller class via Ajax Jquery.
(I know my $.ajax is empty, this is just a example...)

```
$.ajax({
               url: 'php/Sys/Controllers/ControllerUsuario.php',
               type: 'POST',
               data: { },
               error: function() {

               },
               success: function(data) {

               }
            });
        });
```

Here is my PHP Class

```
class ControllerUsuario
{
   private $modelUsuario;
    private $action;

    /*public function actionUsuario(  ){
        //$codigo = $_POST[codigo];
        $this->modelUsuario = new ModelUsuario();
        $this->modelUsuario->setCodigo($codigo);
        return (new ViewUsuario($this->modelUsuario->selecionarUsuario()))->renderUsuario();
    }*/

    public function __construct($action) {
        $this->action = $action;

        switch ($this->action) {
            case 'actionUsuario':
                //$codigo = $_POST["codigo"];
                $this->modelUsuario = new ModelUsuario();
                $this->modelUsuario->setCodigo(1);
                return (new ViewUsuario($this->modelUsuario->selecionarUsuario()))->renderUsuario();
                break;

            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Someone can help-me? please?

Comment: Your ajax call looks syntatically correct, though your data object is empty.  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify your question 
as i understand from your question that you need to send data from ajax to you controller

You need to create object of your data
Ex. Ajax call

```
     $.ajax({
           url: 'php/Sys/Controllers/ControllerUsuario.php',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {action: "actionUsuario", codigo: "Test"},
           error: function() {

           },
           success: function(data) {

           }
        });
    });
```

and add this to end of your your controller

```
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action']){
 return new ControllerUsuario($_POST['action']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a Handler to get all data and after that I pass the values to the class, because my problem was with the $_POST inside the constructor class. It was giving me a problem. Error. I solved this. Thank you guys for Helping.